# How to push similar object elements in single array using node js?

Tags: arrays, node.js, postgresql, for-loop

I am retrieving some data from PostgreSQL using node js API call. In this I am using 2 different pg tables. I am checking condition if "unit_code" is equal to "fk_unit_code" then it should combine the respective values from "Group_individuals" column and push it to the array. To get the "userData" I am doing left join between 2 tables. I have tried below code but its pushing single row per iteration of for loop.

```
function buildObject(userData){

for (var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
myArray = new Array() // at each iteration this will be empty and we get new group of "Group_individuals"
if(userData[i].unit_code=== userData[i].fk_unit_code){

                        myArray.push(userData[i].Group_individuals)
                        console.log(myArray)

            }
     }
}
```

Data available in "userData" is as below:

```
[
    { Group_individuals  : 'John',
      unit_code   : 2,
      fk_unit_code: 2,
    }
    { Group_individuals  : 'Rocky',
      unit_code   : 2,
      fk_unit_code: 2,
    }
    { Group_individuals  : 'Alex',
      unit_code   : 3,
      fk_unit_code: 3,
    }
    { Group_individuals  : 'Prince',
      unit_code   : 3,
      fk_unit_code: 3,
    }
    { Group_individuals  : 'James',
      unit_code   : 2,
      fk_unit_code: 2,
    }

]
```

I want that myArray should look like:
In first iteration myArray = [John, Rocky, James]
In second iteration myArray = [Alex, Prince]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var userData = [{
     Group_individuals: 'John',
     unit_code: 2,
     fk_unit_code: 2,
    },{
     Group_individuals: 'Rocky',
     unit_code: 2,
     fk_unit_code: 2,
    },{
     Group_individuals: 'Alex',
     unit_code: 3,
     fk_unit_code: 3,
    },{
     Group_individuals: 'Prince',
     unit_code: 3,
     fk_unit_code: 3,
    },{
     Group_individuals: 'James',
     unit_code: 2,
     fk_unit_code: 2,
    }]
    var result = {};
    
    for (var i in userData) {
     if (userData[i].unit_code != userData[i].fk_unit_code)
      continue;
     var key = `${userData[i].unit_code}${userData[i].fk_unit_code}`;
    
     result[key] = result[key] || [];
    
     result[key].push(userData[i].Group_individuals);
    
    }
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: might be nice to explain this answer to OP so they can learn a bit (as well as future readers too)

Comment: @vcode Your answer is really appreciated, This helped me to achieve what I was expecting. 

Thank you !!!